# Making a CURL POST request to server in C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, rest, curl, post, httpwebrequest

I am attempting to make a POST request to a server. The following works when I CURL using git Bash:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -H "User-Agent: MyUserAgent" --data-binary @MyDocument.xlsx http://myUrl.com
```

I know I can make POST requests using json as follows (in C#):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.UserAgent = myUserAgent;
using (var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
{
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(myJsonData);
    }
}
using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //do stuff with response
    }
}
```

My difficulty is basically combining the two. I know I need to change the request.ContentType to "application/octet-stream", but that is not enough. How do I incorporate the "--data-binary @MyDocument.xlsx" in the HttpWebRequest?
Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into `WebClient` since it's easier to implement:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] response = client.UploadFile(myUrl,fileName);
```